# node.js inspecting dom like standard javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

How is it possible to create `document` object from html source and use `document.*` functions like `getElementById` in node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to use a jQuery-like API to traverse and fiddle with HTML markup, a better option is [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio).

jsdom is a full-fledged DOM implementation that can even run the JS that comes with a page.  As a result, it's pretty heavy.  If you don't need any of that functionality, cheerio is 8x faster.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
//=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```

Answer (score 11):

You probably want something like the javascript implementation of the DOM, [jsdom](http://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).